# Where comment? What is the Latin term “pace” used for when referencing other scholars?

Tags: discussion

[citations - What is the Latin term "pace" used for when referencing other scholars? - Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/131398/what-is-the-latin-term-pace-used-for-when-referencing-other-scholars/133655#comment349204_131398)

> However, I can imagine that some authors simply use *pace* for variation from "contrary to" without this particular nuance (essentially as [suggested in the comments](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/131398/what-is-the-latin-term-pace-used-for-when-referencing-other-scholars/133655#comment349204_131398)). (As may be clear from my question, this was in the field of linguistics and written by an author with an exceptional sensitivity to the finer nuances of language.)

When I click "suggested in the comments", I don't see comment. Just question. This comment deleted? Can you post it thanks?

Answer (score 3):

The comment did not include any new information. I removed the reference.

In the future, if you see something like this, please just flag it for moderator attention as only moderators can see deleted comments anyway.